# How to send the data to Loading Html page directly without any request while the data is getting processed in views.py in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am having a method in the Django view which has a loop. Each sentence from the loop is getting processed and the final output is sent to the html. Meanwhile i would like to show that the particular sentence is getting processed on the same html page.

views.py

```
def get_String(request):
    Parameter = request.POST.get('search_Key')
    Data1 = data.objects.all()
    for item in Data1:
        print(item.Sentence)
        Output1 = returnResult1(Parameter ,item.Sentence)
        Output2 = returnResult2(Parameter ,item.Sentence)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"searched_key":Parameter,"Result1": Output1,"Result2":Output2}),content_type="application/json")
```

The sentence one by one getting processed and the final output is shown. Meanwhile I need to show that, the current item.Sentence is only getting processed in the below HTML which is actually shown at the time of processing.

Loading.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% csrf_token %}

<div id="progress1"><font size="2">
Loading... the processing sentence is: {{ List }}</font>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly let me know how to send the Sentence directly from views.py to Loading.html page without any request.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do must be done on the client side of your app.

a simple way to do this is to disable the submit input and add a spinner to it through javascript.

assuming you use jQuery and have fontawesome:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("SUBMIT BUTTON SELECTOR").click(function(){
    var spinner = $("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></spin>");
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled").prepend(spinner);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I don't want to add a spinner...instead I want to show which sentence is getting processed in the loop while its taking time to load the final results...

Comment: still a client side thing, just that you'll need to delete the DOM's content and insert your desired result